# Show divs in dependency of value in localStorage - Angular 5

Tags: angular

i'm thinking what would be the best way to solve this. I have a small admin-view inside my application which is overloaded right now. So i want to show up three buttons and let the user choose, what he wants to do like:

```
<button (click)=loadFooForm()>Foo</button>
<button (click)=loadBarForm()>Bar</button>
<button (click)=loadFooBarForm()>FooBar</button>
```

After the user has selected one of those buttons, right under them there should appear the correct form. So i thought about setting a value in `localStorage` by clicking onto one of the buttons and then use `*ngIf`, checking which form is activated and show it up. But would that be the correct / best way? Do you have any other tipps or tricks for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume there are 3 different forms and each form is it's own component?

You could just put some basic visibility properties on your component like the following:

```
public fooFormVisible = false;
public barFormVisible = false;
public fooBarFormVisible = false;
```

Each method can just set the visibility

```
public loadFooForm() {
    this.fooFormVisible = true;
}
```

Or you can just change the click event in your view:

```
<button (click)="fooFormVisible = true">Foo</button>
```

in your view you can then just have some simple `*ngIf` directives on the forms

```
<foo-Form *ngif="fooFormVisible" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that helped me a lot. How can i add transition between those three forms? Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: @Sithys As in animation transition?